# C# bitwise shift on ushort (UInt16)

Tags: c#, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, 16-bit

I need to perform a bitwise left shift on a 16-bit integer (ushort / UInt16), but the bitwise operators in C# seem to apply to int (32-bit) only. How can I use << on an ushort, or at least get to the same result with a simple workaround?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Cast the resulting value back into ushort after shifting:

```
ushort value = 1;
ushort shifted = (ushort)(value << 2);
```

Comment: will `value` be implicitly converted to `uint` for the `<<` operator?

Comment: almost embarrassing, so simply this was :) I did almost the same, but forgot the brackets around (value << 2)

Comment: @xtofl, value will be implicitly converted to int.

Comment: @xtofl, `int` as @driis says. Note also that in this case, and many similar cases, the result will be the same either way.